# Flask help understanding primaryjoin/secondaryjoin on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, relationship

I have the classes User and Listing, and I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship so that a User can have many favorite listings, and any listing can be favorited by many users.

I've been using [this](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers-contacts-and-friends) as a reference but this is my first many-to-many relationship so any help would be appreciated.

> InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't
>   proceed with initialization of other mappers. Original exception was:
>   Could not determine relationship direction for primaryjoin condition
>   'favorites_table.user_id = :user_id_1', on relationship
>   User.favorites. Ensure that the referencing Column objects have a
>   ForeignKey present, or are otherwise part of a ForeignKeyConstraint on
>   their parent Table, or specify the foreign_keys parameter to this
>   relationship.

**models.py**

```
favorites_table = db.Table('favorites_table',
  db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('listing.id')),
  db.Column('listing_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  listings = db.relationship('Listing', backref = 'manager', lazy = 'dynamic')
  favorites  = db.relationship('Listing',
    secondary=favorites_table,
    primaryjoin = ('favorites_table.c.user_id == id'), 
    secondaryjoin = ('favorites_table.c.listing_id == id'),
    backref = db.backref('user', lazy = 'dynamic'),
    lazy = 'dynamic')

  def favorite_listing(self, listing):
    if not self.is_favorite(listing):
    self.favorites.append(listing)
    return self

  def unfavorite_listing(self, listing):
    if self.is_favorite(listing):
    self.favorites.remove(listing)
    return self

  def is_favorite(self, listing):
    return self.favorites.filter(favorites_table.c.listing_id == listing.id).count() > 0


class Listing(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Comment: Why do you specify the primary/secondary join conditions as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your model has all required `ForeignKey`s specified, sqlachemy is smart enough to figure out the parameters for `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` itself. So this should work just fine:

```
favorites  = db.relationship('Listing',
    secondary = favorites_table,
    # primaryjoin = 'favorites_table.c.user_id == User.id',
    # secondaryjoin = 'favorites_table.c.listing_id == Listing.id',
    backref = db.backref('users', lazy = 'dynamic'),
    lazy = 'dynamic',
    )
```

If you really wish to be explicit, you can uncomment the two rows above for exactly the same result. Note that I added a model name before each `id` column specified.

*Please note that in your `favorites_table` relationship table column `user_id` points to `Listing.id` while `listing_id -> User.id`, while it looks like it should be the other way around.*

Comment: @van what exactly does primaryjoin/secondaryjoin do?